# Getting and displaying data from many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using .net mvc core. I have a many to many relationship with 3 tables: Courses, Lecturers, CourseLecturers. (CourseLecturers being the junction table)
**What i want to do, is to show all lecturers for one Course entry, so it would be like a table with 3 columns: Id, CourseName and Lecturers. And i have an issue with getting the data, and then displaying it.** And the point of it is to show all lecturers for a subject (For example if there are one or more Lecturers). Now i am unsure how to achieve this. Since my View will only take my Courses model. And i am unsure how to access the Lecturer names over EF.

As far as i see it, i should select all Entries from CourseLecturers where id of Course is equal to my CourseId, and then to somehow connect the id of the other part of primary key in my CourseLecturers table (LecturerId) and select all the Lecturers with the key i have. At this point i am neither sure how to select the data, and how to show it.

This is my model for Courses :

```
public partial class Courses
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
}
```

This is my model for Lecturers :

```
public partial class Lecturers
{
   [Key]
    public int LecturerId { get; set; }
    public string Lecturer { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my model for CourseLecturers :

```
public partial class CourseLecturers
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Courses))]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Courses Courses { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Lecturers))]
    public int LecturerId { get; set; }
    public Lecturers Lecturers { get; set; }
}
```

Should i maybe add the CourseLecturers class inside of my Courses class, and then try to access the data like that ? But if that works, how to display the data, do i create a new DisplayClass in my model, and then pass that DisplayClass to the view ?

This is my Index method in controller :

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Courses.Include(c => c.CourseLecturers).ThenInclude(cl => cl.Lecturers)); 
    }
```

And my view looks like this :

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseTitle)
        </td>
        <td>

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.CourseLecturers.Lecturers.Lecturer)

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And this is what gets displayed : 
http://imgur.com/a/lVZ0Q

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) , which explains in details how to create a data model with Many to Many relationships using [EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) in [ASP.Net MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: The problem is not creating a relationship, the problem i have is to display data, because my view for some reason duplicates the course for which i have more than one lecturer.

Comment: Can you post the view

Comment: There, i added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Is this used read only. I'd define a view in your DB which will be much faster then EF and create a read-only entity for accessing the items.